# Beaglebone PWM limited to 100 HZ?

Tags: beagleboneblack, pwm

I am using Beaglebone not Beaglebone Black.

I just tried to output a PWM and I expected potential frequencies of some megaherz on such a fast device.
I found out that 100HZ is the exact maximum I can set through sysfs.
I started digging online for examples and they did not mention a limit but they also did not show an value faster than 100HZ.

Example:

```
root@beaglebone:/sys/class/pwm/ehrpwm.0:0# echo 10000000 >  period_ns 
root@beaglebone:/sys/class/pwm/ehrpwm.0:0# echo 1000000 >  period_ns 
-sh: echo: write error: Invalid argument
root@beaglebone:/sys/class/pwm/ehrpwm.0:0# echo 200 >  period_freq 
-sh: echo: write error: Invalid argument
root@beaglebone:/sys/class/pwm/ehrpwm.0:0# echo 101 >  period_freq 
-sh: echo: write error: Invalid argument
root@beaglebone:/sys/class/pwm/ehrpwm.0:0# echo 100 >  period_freq 
root@beaglebone:/sys/class/pwm/ehrpwm.0:0#
```

Any 10cent AVR can do a faster PWM than that.
Is there some trick I missed?
Do I really have to create a custom PWM by manuallz toggling GPIO if I want a faster frequency than 100 HZ ?!

Comment: I am not sure why you want a cycle rate less than 1 hz. PWM is duty cycle and frequency. Duty cycle is the percentage of on-time to off-time in 1 cycle. Frequency is how many cycles in a 1 second. The beaglebone black runs best at 2000 hz if more than 1 pwm channel is run simultaneously but I have had it work at different frequencies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I actually found the solution just shortly after opening my question.
I will post it here as I think this might actually cause more than just me to wonder :)

The PWM frequency is of course not limited like that on a 1GHZ device, the kernel driver is just not working in the same way one would expect.

If you enter a duty_percent value (like 1 percent) then the driver seems to just calculate the duty_ns value out of it and forget about percent afterward.
A normal user would think he is in "percent mode" but actually the percentage file is just bound to a wrapper to help.
The same counts for the frequency!
If you now change the frequency to a higher value then then the kernel checks if the duty_ns cycle period fits into the new total period_ns!
It ignores that you actually set a percentage!

So of course you can not have an on-period which is larger than the whole period, so it fails.

Long text short summary:
**Always set duty_cycle to zero BEFORE you set the frequency if the previous value will not fit into the new period, this avoids frustration.**

Comment: For the sake of completeness: I measured the smallest possible pulse step size to be 10 ns. Furthermore, the pulse width timer has a 16 Bit resolution. So be aware of rounding problems.

Comment: Also I think using the PWM for realtime jobs (like flight control) is not a good idea if you have an non RT OS behind it (like standard Linux)
I stopped from using the PWM of beaglebone for such a job, it is not reliable enough regarding the timing.
A good solution is to add a small AVR through I2C or SPI or similar and use that for the realtime jobs and PWM.

Comment: @Dietrich: you mean 65535ns is max you can set ?

Comment: @xmen W.K: (Took a while to get the BB running again..). The maximum period I could set was 1 second. Since the hardware registers are 16 Bit and they are scaled to the period, it means that the duty cycle resolution is worse than a 65536-th of the period despite of other values in the SysFs interface.

Comment: @Dietrich:16 bit sucks. So cant set frequency 5Hz or lower. Do you know anything that can generate PWM at low frequency like 5Hz and duty cycle 1000us ?

Comment: @xmen W.K: No I don't know a high level solution. If you're into low level programming, read the AM335x Tech Manual. The BB's PWM hardware is quite sophisticated - only a small fraction is used in the kernel driver. If you can live with some jitter, you just can write a C programm for a GPIO pin; if it should be with less jitter use the BB's PRU.